# Conjecture about primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, conjectures

Let $n_0$ be an integer (positive or negative). Are
there infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p + n_0 = {2^r} · q,$ $ r ≥ 0,$ $ q ≥ 3 $ is prime?

When $n_0 = 2$, this conjecture is the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: This is a special case of Hypothesis H https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H  . So very likely true, and very likely that it won't be proven any time soon.

Comment: (Or even Dickson's conjecture, half a century earlier.)

Answer (score 2):

[I may be misinterpreting the question.]

Let $n_0=-1$. It is known that there are infinitely many odd numbers $q$ such that $2^rq+1$ is composite for all $r$. $q=271129$ is such a number, and it is prime. See https://oeis.org/A076336

Comment: I do not know any counter-examples when $n_0$ is odd. When $n_0$ is even，this is the general twin prime conjecture.